# Pattern matching failing for valid pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

I have the following code:

```
import Debug.Trace (trace)

mtrace :: Show a => String -> a -> a
mtrace msg value =
  trace (msg ++ show value) value

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel = (`elem` "AEIOU")

vowelSlice :: String -> ([Maybe Char], String)
vowelSlice "" = ([], [])
vowelSlice (c:s)
    | isVowel c = (Nothing:chars, c:vowels)
    | otherwise = (Just c:chars, vowels)
    where (chars, vowels) = vowelSlice s

stringTogether :: [Maybe Char] -> String -> String
stringTogether [] "" = ""
stringTogehter (Just c:cs) vowels = c:stringTogether cs vowels
stringTogehter (Nothing:cs) (v:vs) = v:stringTogether cs vs

process :: String -> String
process s = stringTogether (mtrace "chars: " chars) (mtrace "vowels: " cycledVowels)
    where
      (chars, vowels) = vowelSlice s
      cycledVowels = tail vowels ++ [head vowels]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    putStrLn $ process line
```

for testing I run my file using the `runhaskell` command and the I enter `HELLO PEOPLE` as user input once the program is running. I'm expecting the output: `HELLE POEPLO` or something similar since my program is meant to shift the vowels only. My program works fine until it tries to run  the `stringTogether` method. Specifically the issue lies with the pattern matching, I have an array:

```
[Just 'H',Nothing,Just 'L',Just 'L',Nothing,Just ' ',Just 'P',Nothing,Nothing,Just 'P',Just 'L',Nothing]
```

and a pattern
`(Just c:cs) vowels` that I expect it to match but somehow it doesn't seem to work. When I run the code and enter `HELLO WORLD` I receive the following error:
`18:1-25: Non-exhaustive patterns in function stringTogether` I logged a few things using the trace module and everything looks as expected before entering the `stringTogether` function

I'm probably overlooking something really obvious but I just can't get my head around why the pattern match won't work, I hope someone is able to help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: it is possible that one of the two lists is *not* empty whereas the other is.

Comment: Here you forgot the cases where it has `(Nothing:_) []`.

Comment: Yeah my editor warned me that my patterns are not exhaustive and I tried adding a general catch all pattern at the end but it would catch every function call. Also because the function `stringTogether` is always called with input generated from `vowelSlice` it shouldn't fail.

Comment: but you make a recursive call here, so eventually the lists will get exhausted.

Comment: When you get unexpected warnings, look for typos. That's all the problem here is.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern match fails because of a typo, 2 separate functions were defined instead of the intended one: `stringTogether` and `stringTogehter`. The patterns were valid but the compiler failed to find them because they had mismatching names. The function technically `stringTogether` only had one pattern `[] ""` so when the list was passed it raised the `18:1-25: Non-exhaustive patterns in function stringTogether` error.